# What is the best approach to tackle stance prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, nlp

I am working on a task where I need to predict one of the following stances for a tweet: "In favor", "Against", "Neutral", "Not related", and "Yes if". I've been trying to use scikit-learn and transformers for classification, but both seem to produce quite poor results. The problem is that the categories are not usual categories, but rather the attitude of the writer toward a specific topic, which probably should be tackled differently. I think there should be something that works with stances, but I managed to find only sentiment analysis and topic modeling tutorials so far. Is there anything I can take a look at? Any links, models, and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could fit two (or three) models. The first one asks is the question "related" or not? Then you can fit to 4 ordinal classifications. Finally, if you wanted to get even fancier, you could add a model to analyze your Yes responses and deterimine if they were a "Yes if" or not.

This is likely not optimal but just an approach.

The obvious alternative is fit to 5 categorical levels with no sense of scale or order. Probably less efficient though.

Comment: Hm, interesting, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: I'll leave the question open for some time, and will accept it as an answer if there are no others

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi, if this answer answered your question, accepting it would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, sorry, accepted it as an answer!